# Delete function binary search tree BST with parent passing the tree pointer as argument

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am having a very difficult time understanding what my book is wanting me to learn. I am currently re-vising some algorithms and data structure material I studied quite some years ago. One chapter is about Binary Search Tree and their application, etc. The book talks about a BST (binary search tree) as a tree with nodes that has the following qualities: `int data, node left, node right, node parent`. I understand this and I have implemented a search function.

Now to the issue: How do I create a delete function when the arguments I have are `N* delete(Tree* tree, N* delete_node);`?

There are lots of recursive functions but they rely on the fact that we recursively pass a pointer of a node and a key value. This is not what the exercise in the book is looking for. An example of a method that I have tried and works is: [source code for C Program for Insertion and Deletion in Binary Search Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43643631/15356227). Two other great sources that fails to meet these criteria are [codezclub](http://www.codezclub.com/c-binary-tree-deletion-without-recursion/) and [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/). They solve the "delete" function but their function have other parameters in their function. My book specifies

> A modifying operation that, given a pointer delete_node to an
> element in the BST, tree, deletes delete_node from the BST tree and returns its pointer.
>
> Function declaration: N* delete(Tree* tree, N* delete_node);

Anybody got any ideas? Also minimally reproducible examples are given in the sources above with the caviat that the structs are missing "parent" node. Below are my definitions for the tree and the node:

```
typedef struct N {
    int data;
    struct N* left;
    struct N* right;
    struct N* parent;
} N;

typedef struct Tree {
    N* root;
} Tree;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) as a reference for understanding `Binary search tree` data structures and operations on it. Let's implement `delete` procedure first and then explain necessary parts. 
We need `2` procedures, `SUCCESSOR` and `transplant` other than `delete` itself to make it complete. required procedures are implement before `delete`.

> In order to move subtrees around within the binary search tree, we define a
> subroutine transplant, which replaces one subtree as a child of its parent with
> another subtree. When transplant replaces the subtree rooted at node u with
> the subtree rooted at node v, node u’s parent becomes node v’s parent, and u’s
> parent ends up having v as its appropriate child.

```
void transplant(Tree** root, Tree* u, Tree* v) {
    if(u == NULL)
        return;
    else if(u->parent == NULL)
        *root = v;
    else if(u->parent->left == u)
        u->parent->left = v;
    else
        u->parent->right = v;
    if(v != NULL)
        v->parent = u->parent;
}
```

We need to implement `Tree* SUCCESSOR(Tree* T)` procedure which returns the `node` where `node->key` is the next larger element greater than `T->key`, if it exists. otherwise, returns `NULL`. We need `SUCCESSOR` when `delete_node` has 2 children. It'll be replaced with the `SUCCESSOR(delete_node)`.

```
Tree* SUCCESSOR(Tree* T) {
    if(T == NULL)
        return T; // Since T==NULL, it's equivalent to return NULL
    else if(T->left != NULL) {
        while(T->left != NULL)
            T=T->left;
        return T;
    }
    else {
        while(T->parent != NULL && T->parent->right == T)
            T = T->parent;
        return T->parent;
    }
}
```

We can all needed to implement `delete` procedure.

```
Tree* delete(Tree* root, Tree* delete_node) {
    if(delete_node == NULL)
        return root;
    
    if(delete_node->left== NULL)
        transplant(&root, delete_node, delete_node->right);

    else if(delete_node->right == NULL)
        transplant(&root, delete_node, delete_node->left);

    else {
        Tree* succ = SUCCESSOR(delete_node);
        if(delete_node->right != succ) {
            transplant(&root, succ , succ ->right);
            succ->right = delete_node->right;
            succ->right->parent = succ;
        }
        transplant(&root, delete_node, succ);
        succ->left = delete_node->left;
        succ->left->parent = succ;
    }
    return root;
}
```

Here's how `delete` procedure works:

> The procedure for deleting a given node `delete_node` from a binary search tree `root` takes as arguments pointers to `root` and `delete_node`. It organizes its cases a bit differently from the three mentioned above.
>
> - If `delete_node` has no left child (first `if` statement do this part), then we replace `delete_node` by its right child, which may or may not be `NULL`. When `delete_node`'s right child is NULL, this case deals with the situation in which `delete_node` has no children. When `delete_node`'s right child is non-NULL, this case handles the situation in which `delete_node` has just one child, which is its right child.
> - If `delete_node` has just one child, which is its left child (`else if` part handles this case), then we replace `delete_node` by its left child.
> - Otherwise, `delete_node` has both a left and a right child. We find `delete_node`’s successor `succ`, which lies in `delete_node`’s right subtree and has no left child (If it has a left, child, then it's not the smallest number greater than `delete_node->key`. We get contradiction). We want to splice `succ` out of its current location and have it replace `delete_node` in the tree.
>
>   - If `succ` is `delete_node`'s right child, then we replace `delete_node` by `succ`.
>   - Otherwise, `succ` lies within `delete_node`’s right subtree but is not `delete_node`'s right child. In this case, we first replace `succ` by its own right child, and then we replace `delete_node` by `succ`.

Since both quotes are taken from[CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms), I encourage you to review it in case of having problem in understanding why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do deletion without recursive function.

```
typedef struct N {
    int data;
    struct N* left;
    struct N* right;
    struct N* parent;
} N;

typedef struct Tree {
    N* root;
} Tree;

N* delete(Tree* tree, N* delete_node);
```

Lets start from this definition. Well, have to say the delete function is uncommon, given the fact that in most cases we are using:

> void delete(Tree* tree, int element);

Because we don't know whether the element exists or not (it need to be determined by contains() or find() function when we execute the deletion), and we don't need any return value most likely.
Anyway lets put it your way.

Deleting from BST is complicated and you should proceed with three basic situation:

1. The node you want to delete is leaf, i.e. it has no child;
2. The node has one child, either left or right;
3. The node have both right and left child.

These situations are different in processing, and for simplicity we will omit some implementation details and safety checks, but don't forget them in production code.

In situation 1, you simply free the memory, and change the pointer in its parent to NULL:

```
if (delete_node->parent->data < delete_node->data)
    delete_node->parent->right = NULL; // WARNING: corner case
else
    delete_node->parent->left= NULL; // WARNING: corner case

free(delete_node);
```

Situation 2 is pretty like Situation 1; instead of NULL, we need to change the pointer in parent node to its only child, then we free the node. The logic is similar and we will skip the code.

Situation 3 is a little more complicated. Generally we have two ways and both of them works; either we replace the node's data with largest (in BST we can say "rightest") data of its left subtree, or we replace the node's data with smallest/leftest data of its right subtree. After the replacing, we remove that node instead. Let's examine the second approach, i.e. replace the node's data with smallest data of its right subtree. The first approach has very similar logic.

For this approach, we need this function implemented:

```
N* findMin(N* root_of_subtree);
```

It will take root_of_subtree as input (search will start from this node), and returns the pointer to the desired, smallest node.

Assume we have found the desired smallest node in the right subtree of delete_node:

```
N* smallestNodeOfRightSubtree = findMin(delete_node->right);

delete_node->data = smallestNodeOfRightSubtree->data;
smallestNodeOfRightSubtree->parent->left = smallestNodeOfRightSubtree->right; // WARNING, corner case
free(smallestNodeOfRightSubtree);
```

We directly changed parent->left here, since in **general** case (corner case 2 explains what is not general), that node has two charateristics:

1. It has no left child.
2. It must be on the left subtree of its parents.

But, it is not always general, we still have some corner cases need to cover:

1. What if delete_node is root node? It has no parent, and code in Situation 1 will be undefined behavior.
2. What if the smallest node of the right subtree of delete_node is delete_node->right, i.e. the right subtree only have 1 node. In this case, we cannot change smallestNodeOfRightSubtree->parent->left; instead, we should change parent->right.

THAT'S IT. Now you know the logics, and some corner cases. GL & HF.